# Rails Dockerfile no longer building, unable to install racc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems, nokogiri, alpine-linux

I have been working with the same Dockerfile for months on a rails api and suddenly it will no longer build. I am getting an error everytime it tries to install racc :

```
#11 7.201 Installing racc 1.6.0 with native extensions
#11 7.598 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
#11 7.598
#11 7.598     current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/racc-1.6.0/ext/racc/cparse
#11 7.598 /usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r
#11 7.598 ./siteconf20211027-1-1m7t8pg.rb extconf.rb
#11 7.598 checking for rb_block_call()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
#11 7.598 Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
#11 7.598 libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
#11 7.598 need configuration options.
```

It's so strange that it was working fine until this afternoon. Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.4-alpine

ENV APP_PATH /api
ENV RAILS_PORT 3000

# install dependencies for application these are specific to alpine
RUN apk -U add --no-cache --update \
build-base \
git \
vim \
postgresql-dev \
postgresql-client \
ruby-diff-lcs \
libxml2-dev \
libxslt-dev \
linux-headers \
nodejs \
yarn \
imagemagick \
tzdata \
less \
ruby-nokogiri \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
&& mkdir -p $APP_PATH 

# navigate to app directory
WORKDIR $APP_PATH

COPY Gemfile ${APP_PATH}/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock ${APP_PATH}/Gemfile.lock

RUN mkdir -p ${APP_PATH}/log && touch ${APP_PATH}/log/development.log

RUN bundle install

COPY . $APP_PATH
RUN gem install foreman
```

and my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem 'rack-cors'

# Devise and Json Web Token deps
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-jwt'
gem 'fast_jsonapi'

# QR Code Generator
gem "rqrcode", "~> 2.0"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  # testing stuff
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Any help or suggestions appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked the mkmf.log file for more details?

Comment: @dbugger I have not checked the log. I did just delete the container and then when it rebuilt it worked fine so I'm not sure what the issue was- but it must have been some caching issue with docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Ruby 2.7 has support for racc version 1.4.x as a "native gem". Understanding that bundler tries to update it, have somewhere in your Gemfile

```
    gem "racc", "~> 1.4.0"
```

Go on to clear your Gemfile.lock, and run bundle to update it.

This should prevent bundler from trying to update racc and provides racc version 1.4.x as a dependency, thus preventing the "build gem native extension" error.

Here's a [link](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#cannot-install-racc) to some helpful documentation on this racc issue and other common nokogiri issues.